# Grouping favorite questions into lists on your profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, bookmarks, list-questions

I favorite some questions from time to time, but usually they are related to a specific project I am working on. For example, while working on Project A (a Java Project), I might favorite a couple of questions related to Java. A couple of weeks later, I might be on Project B (a C++ Project) and would favorite several questions related to that. And later down the line, after many other projects, I might revisit one of these past projects and need to find a question related to the project that I marked as a favorite.

I could sort it by time and guess when it was that I found the question, but that is inefficient. It'd be great if I could sort my favorite questions into groups that make sense to me as I add them, so that I could have relevant questions that helped me on a project all in one accessible place.

Comment: Related: [Classification (or equivalent) option for favorited questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305448/classification-or-equivalent-option-for-favorited-questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the launch of the [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) recently, this is now possible. Custom lists can be created to organize your favorite saved content (now supporting saving answers as well!) As such, I've added the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) label.

Answer (score 3):

**You can!**

Use your browser's favorite / bookmarks bar, create the folders you need, and add the links there.  You're asking for document / file management which is probably not the goal of the site, in addition, you're asking for something that maybe you will use but may bring little value to other users.

The minute the development team introduces such functionality, then they need to be able to support it.  For instance, this brings a whole slew of other things:

- Searching within my folders
- Deleting folders
- Adding new folders
- What if I want to name my favorite
- Tagging favorites
- Sorting
- Moving favorites in and out of other folders

You're basically asking for a feature that is already built into your browser / os than can do all of this.  It should not be implemented on Stack Overflow or any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Using this method does not show you when the questions are updated, which is part of the appeal of marking a question as a favorite on SO. While I admit it works- I don't think this is quite helpful as a workaround if you're trying to keep track of things.

Comment: Kendra - I can agree with that - but can you think about (and I listed some of them) how many other things the developers would have to support.  Its like saying we should get rid of outlook email and just use notifications for every site we use.  The site owners (the programmers) than have to mimic those outlook features...To me its very low priority.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a priority- I'm just saying that this does work, but not quite in a way most of us would desire. It's a good back-up method at the very least.

Comment: @JonH : Since every favourite question has multiple global tags associated with it. So can't we achieve it by introducing the local (local to user) custom tags? This way we can still group our questions and filter them. I think this should require lesser dev efforts as compared to full folder mechanism approach shared by you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you know you can [limit your search to your own favorite questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)?  For example, when you are working on your Java project, you could search for:

```
infavorites:mine [java]
```